# Why does relatively positioning the body influence absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

So with the code below, when I change the margin of bar, the position of foo changes. But this only happens when the body is relatively positioned. If I statically position the body, then the position of foo no longer depends on the margin of bar. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   * {
    margin:0;
   }

   body {
    position:relative;
   }

   #foo {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
   }

   #bar {
    margin:100px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="foo">asdf</div>
  <div id="bar">asdf</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are anchored by their closest absolutely, or relatively positioned parent.

EDIT: For added clarity about the margin please see my comment below.

EDIT2: This also applies to elements with a fixed position.

Comment: I probably just don't understand, but I don't see how this answers the question at all. How does this explain why the margin of bar is relevant when the body is relatively positioned? Bar is neither relatively nor absolutely positioned.

Comment: The body has no margin.  When the margin is applied to bar it bleeds through the body pushing the body down.  This is known as collapsing margins.  This happens whether the body is relative or static.  Adding relative to the body however forces foo to be anchored by the corner of body.  Since the margin of bar forces the corner of body down it affects the positioning of foo as well.

Comment: I think you should use the word "ancestor" in place of "parent" and that parent can also be `position:fixed` - so long as the ancestor isn't statically positioned.

Comment: @Jrod Collapsing margins refers to mergin the margins of two /adjacent/ elements, not a parent element and a child element.  Also, foo is anchored to the top-left corner of body, so body's height should not affect its positioning.

Comment: Hmm when I add a red border to body, it (the red border) is at the very top of the screen, no matter how large the margin of bar. If the body were pushed down, wouldn't this red border also be pushed down?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen.  While I agree about adding position:fixed, why replace ancestor with parent?  They are synonymous.

Comment: @zjmiller By adding a border you remove the ability of the collapsing margin.

Comment: @Jrod - No they're not! That's like saying rectangles and squares mean the same thing. A parent is the *immediate* ancestor of an element.

Comment: @mwcz "In this specification, the expression collapsing margins means that adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin."  W3 Specification http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090423/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: @Jrod Cool, I never knew that.  Thanks.  But still, how does the height of body affect the placement of an element anchored to the top-left?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen In my experience parent is interchangeable with ancestor.  I apologize if my use of this doesn't sit well with you.

Comment: @mwcz Don't think I ever mentioned the height of the body.

Comment: @Jrod Ah, I misunderstood 'pushing the body down' in your first comment.  Upvoted now that what you're saying finally clicked with me.

Comment: @Jrod Great, thanks for the follow-up. I toyed around some more and noticed that adding a border or padding to body severs the relationship between bar's margin and foo's position, as we'd expect if margin collapsing were the relevant factor.

Answer (score 0):

Jrod nailed it, the default positioning is always top left of the browser window. By default positioning is Relative, for every element added (children) will follow these same guidelines.

You have given #foo coordinates to follow whereas all you have given #bar is a margin to follow in Relative relation to the Body.

Comment: Check out my comments to the other two answers. Bar is not a parent of foo. It is also neither absolutely nor relatively positioned. Why would its margin affect the placement of an absolutely positioned element? And why does this effect only occur when the body is relatively positioned?

Comment: Default positioning is not relative but static.

Comment: By default, elements are not relatively positioned: they are statically positioned (a.k.a no positioned).